# Cherrypy server unavailable from anything but localhost

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am having an issue with cherrypy that looks solved, but doesn't work.  I can only bind on localhost or 127.0.0.1. Windows XP Home and Mac OS X (linux untested), cherrypy 3.1.2, python 2.5.4. This is the end of my app:

```
global_conf = {
       'global':    { 'server.environment= "production"'
                      'engine.autoreload_on : True'
                      'engine.autoreload_frequency = 5 '
                      'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                      'server.socket_port': 8080}
    }
cherrypy.config.update(global_conf)
cherrypy.tree.mount(home, '/', config = application_conf)
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Comment: So... what do you mean when you say that it "doesn't work"?

Comment: what host should you be able to bind to? ie what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 7):

huh, you're doing something wrong with your dict:

```
>>> global_conf = {
...        'global':    { 'server.environment= "production"'
...                       'engine.autoreload_on : True'
...                       'engine.autoreload_frequency = 5 '
...                       'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
...                       'server.socket_port': 8080}
...     }
>>> print global_conf
{'global': 
   {'server.environment= "production"engine.autoreload_on : Trueengine.autoreload_frequency = 5 server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
    'server.socket_port': 8080}
}
```

More specifically, there are commas and colons missing from your dict definiton. Each key/value pair must have a colon, and they are separated with commas. Something like this might work:

```
global_conf = {
       'global':    { 'server.environment': 'production',
                      'engine.autoreload_on': True,
                      'engine.autoreload_frequency': 5,
                      'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                      'server.socket_port': 8080,
                    }
              }
```

Check python [dictionary documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a dual-stack OS, it may be that localhost is resolving to ::1 (the IPv6 localhost) and not 127.0.0.1 (the IPv4 localhost).  Try accessing the server using http://127.0.0.1:8080.

Also, if you're using an dual-stack capable OS, you can set server.socket_host to '::', and it will listen on all addresses in IPv6 and IPv4.